# Update a multi-statement Slick 2.1 withDynSession block to Slick 3.0.3

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I have this Slick 2.1 based repo method:

```
def addContentBySourceInfo(userId: UUID, adopted: Boolean, contentId: UUID, contentInfo: ContentWithoutId): Either[ContentAlreadyExistsError, Content] = {

  getDatabase withDynSession {
    val content = contentInfo.toContent(contentId)

    Try {
      ContentTable.query += content
      UserContentTable.query += UserContentModel(userId, contentId, Some(adopted))
    } match {
      case Failure(e:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) =>
        Left(ContentAlreadyExistsError(content.source, content.sourceId))
      case Failure(e) => throw e // could be some other error, and we should fail fast.
      case Success(s) => Right(content)
    }
  }
}
```

Where `getDatabase` simply returns `Database.forURL(..)` from `slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend`.

How would I convert this to be compatible with the `DBIO` api from Slick 3.x?

**Note:** I'd like to keep these methods Synchronous until I'm ready to upgrade my entire repository layer to handle Asynchronous calls (i.e. I don't want to break my repository API just yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
def addContentBySourceInfo(userId: UUID, adopted: Boolean, contentId: UUID, contentInfo: ContentWithoutId): Either[ContentAlreadyExistsError, Content] = {
  val content = contentInfo.toContent(contentId)
  val actions = DBIO.seq(
    ContentTable.query     += content,
    UserContentTable.query += UserContentModel(userId, contentId, Some(adopted))
  )

  Try(Await.result(db.run(actions), Duration.Inf)) match {
    case Failure(e:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) =>
      Left(ContentAlreadyExistsError(content.source, content.sourceId))
    case Failure(e) => throw e
    case Success(s) => Right(content)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just came back to report something similar after watching: https://youtu.be/WvxXz7aklik?t=30m16s